# Can't connect either Xyboard via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I realize this isn't strictly speaking a programming question, but I'd appreciate a tiny bit of leeway here... I'm unable to connect either the xyboard 8" or 10" via USB through ADB.  All my other devices work fine, and I've set the USB Debugging and the Allow unkown content.  Does anyone know if Motorola has done something to prevent ADB connectivity? Or is there some other step that's specific to these devices I'm missing?  I can't find anyone else complaining about this on any other boards, so, I'm really stumped.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tested an 8" and 10" device here at the Sunnyvale offices with a MacBook Pro running Lion (10.7.2) with SDK tools version 16 (current release). Both devices enumerate and show up with 'adb devices' and in MOTODEV Studio.  On this MacBook, MotoCast was previously installed as you mentioned in your post.

It should just be the debug connection that is enumerating via USB.  But, we're speculating that the problem is due to the lack of the underlying MTP software that is needed by Macs and Linux for Honeycomb and ICS devices.  Motocast possibly installs this as a by-product. Perhaps you could uninstall Motocast if you don't need it and try installing the separate MTP app from Google. http://www.android.com/filetransfer/

#### Followup

We uninstalled Motocast and installed the MTP file transfer tool. **This is not enough** to make debugging work. I'll have to get in touch with the product teams for XYBoard to see how they implemented the debugging protocol.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  Yeah, my problem was that I wasn't noticing the apps mounting the Motocast installer, and didn't have it installed (the Xoom works fine without it, like all the other devices)... so, absent any obvious instructions that this software was imperative, and given that the devices were both saying that they're connected, I was just running in circles. In an ideal world, much like the other devices I have, there would be no need for any additional software to run ADB.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Agreed. The extra software requirement was a surprise to us as well. I'm talking with the product team to get an understanding about why they packaged the drivers this way and to see if they will provide a drivers-only release for developers. If that happens, we'll provide them through MOTODEV.  thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I'm leery to say that this is the "correct" solution (since I'm still not clear on what the problem was) but the problem was solved by my installing MotoCast.  Maybe it comes complete with some special sauce, I don't know. At least one of my colleagues had no problem connecting the 8" to his mac, so, maybe it has something to do with my specific config.

In any event... here's the link to MotoCast, in case it comes in handy for someone else experiencing the same oddball behavior.

http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/MotoCast/MotoCast

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know if Motorola has done something to prevent ADB connectivity?

I guarantee that is not the answer. You cannot ship a device with a licensed copy of the Android Market *and* block adb.

> Or is there some other step that's specific to these devices I'm missing?

On Windows, you need the right driver. You can download Motorola's drivers from [their Web site](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/USB_Drivers/).

You might also try a different micro USB cable, assuming you are trying a cable that you have not used with your other devices.

Beyond that, I suggest you try asking on the [MOTODEV support boards](http://community.developer.motorola.com/mtrl/).

Comment: Thanks Commons. I'm actually on a Mac.  Tried several cables, I have so many devices that I'm not sure which cable came with the device, but none of them seem to work on either the 8" or the 10".  I'll give the MOTODEV board a whirl, thanks again.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: It might be you need to fuss with some settings akin to what I have to do on Ubuntu with `udev` rules. I don't do Android development on OS X, so I'm not sure what the mechanics are there.